# Not able to disable battery optimization for apps on Samsung Galaxy A01 Core (Android Go)

Tags: samsung, android-go, battery-saver

I have a Samsung Galaxy A01 Core (SM-A013M) with Android 10 GO. When I tap on "disable battery optimization" for certain apps, it doesn't really do anything, and there's no button to disable the whole thing.

When I first had the prompt to enable it, I tapped "deny" and it just didn't care. Optimization is turned on for EVERY SINGLE APP except for ones that aren't compatible with it.
This is quite annoying because I want widgets and I get notifications of certain messaging apps like 40 mins later if it even wants to get notifications.

Maybe it's that Android GO that doesn't let me modify that stuff, but on the manual, it says that I can just disable it.

I also wonder if there's any way of making an app "unable to be optimized" or exempted by modifying something on the system (having the app as active on developer settings does nothing really)

I'll link a vid of what I'm trying to do.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/962183578312122378/1136452250437431326/2023-08-02_21-09-33.mp4

Comment: While I don't know if Android Go has an effect or not in this case, perhaps [Don't kill my app!'s guide for Samsung devices](https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung) might help.

Comment: nope, they didn't include Android GO guide, although i was able to add widgets to home by downloading a launcher, i'll see if the "dont kill my app" app can fix the other problem

Comment: Your phone is an ultra low budget phone with 1 or 2GB Ram which is a very low amount of RAM for a smartphone. I assume because of this limitation battery optimization can't be disabled.